# Prefix sum problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider an array of size n with all initial values as 0. Perform given ‘m’ add operations from index ‘a’ to ‘b’ and evaluate the highest element in the array. An add operation adds 100 to all elements from a to b (both inclusive).

Example :

```
Input : n = 5 // We consider array {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
        m = 3.
        a = 2, b = 4.
        a = 1, b = 3.
        a = 1, b = 2.
Output : 300

Explanation : 

After I operation -
A : 0 100 100 100 0

After II operation -
A : 100 200 200 100 0

After III operation -
A : 200 300 200 100 0

Highest element : 300
```

The problem and solution is given already here on
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prefix-sum-array-implementation-applications-competitive-programming/. I tried so hard but I am not able to understand mathematically that why it is working.

Comment: You haven't really asked a question.  What is it that you don't understand?  How far through the argument can you get before you get stuck?

Comment: @NickPeterson That how the actual sum operation and prefix sum gives same values in the array.

Comment: Well, you've already been given an explanation about that at the link you yourself provided -- what about the explanation do you find unsatisfying? I repeat my initial question: where do you get stuck?

Comment: My question is, why is it more efficient? It seems you have to compute the prefix sum every time whilst for the pure sum you only have to add the certain bounds..

Comment: @NickPeterson: I am having doubt because I am thinking in generic terms. So If I take array like {1,2,3,4,5} this approach will not work, right? This logic is applicable only when initial values in the array are all same like {0,0,0,0,0} or {1,1,1,1,1}

Comment: Keep a variable $\texttt{maxVal}$ which will be the highest value. Any time you modify a slot you can recalculate  $\texttt{maxVal}$.

Answer (score 1):

For any array $X = (x_1,x_2,\ldots)$, let $f(X)$ be its prefix sum.
$$f(X) = (x_1, x_1+x_2, x_1+x_2+x_3,\ldots)$$
Notice $f$ is linear in its argument. More precisely, for any arrays $X_1, \ldots, X_n$, we have

$$f(X_1+\cdots+X_n) = f(X_1)+\cdots+f(X_n)$$

Let $I_{ab}$ be the operation to adding from 100 to slot $i$ for $a \le i \le b$ and $J_{ab}$ be the operation of adding $100$ to slot $a$, $-100$ to slot $b+1$. Notice $I_{ab} = f(J_{ab})$, we have

$$I_{a_1b_1} + \cdots + I_{a_nb_n} = f(J_{a_1b_1}) + \cdots + f(J_{a_nb_n})
= f(J_{a_1b_1} + \cdots + J_{a_nb_n})$$

That's why the original sum of $I_{ab}$ on LHS equals to the prefix sum of the addition/subtraction of $J_{ab}$ on RHS. All the magic comes down to the linearity of the operation of taking prefix sum.

Comment: But it will not work for an array like {1,2,3,4,5} right?

Comment: What do mean $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$? Do you mean in the original sum, the array is initialized to $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$? If that is the case, in the prefix sum implementation, the array need to be initialized to something that will give you $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ under $f$ (i.e. $\{1,1,1,1,1\}$).

Comment: Yes the array initialized to  {1,2,3,4,5}